# How to implement hierarchical location information

Tags: java, grails, groovy, model, location

I am looking at a greenfield app, and I need to add support for specifying a location, in the vein of [vrbo.com](http://www.vrbo.com/), where you can drill down from the US at large, to a state, region, city/locale.

What's the best way to go about compiling this information?  Is there a third-party source for this?  If not, how best to model it?

I was thinking about whether to allow for user-defining of locations also, but I'm not sure this is wise.

For now I just need to handle the US, but I'd like to be smart about future international support.

I am using Grails/Groovy, but I can use the underlying Java if need be.

Answer (score 3):

[ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166) is a good source of country and country subdivision (states, provinces, etc.) information.  If you dig around, you can download the data files directly from here: http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=iso-codes/iso-codes.git;a=tree.

For cities, the best resource I've found is the [MaxMind cities database](https://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities).  It's a free download.